# Server not reading htaccess file and redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

My site is not reading the htaccess file. Even if I add `Deny from all` at the top, the site loads fine.

Permission is 644. I have a number of sites running on the server so Apache is set up correctly.

This is my virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/

    <Directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

     ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what I'd added to .htaccess file to redirect www to non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I tried adding it to virtualhost as well but it's still not redirecting.

Comment: have you `RewriteEngine On` before `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in .htaccess?

Comment: Is this correct `virtualhost` file?

Comment: @Andra yes and also it was present before the statements in the virtualhost file. @anubhava I thought it was the correct one however there was another virtualhost that was created when I issued the SSL cert with Let's Encrypt which was missing the `AllowOverride All` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After issuing an SSL Certificate with Let's Encrypt I had noticed it had created a duplicate conf file for port 443:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf`

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:443>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/

  <Directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

  </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
  ```

Prior to the LE, the original `example.com.conf` didn't have the `AllowOverride All` directive. So I assume what has happened is the contents were duplicated and then I only changed the original one.